# cakephp FFMPEG Library to convert mov file into mp4 for iphone to android video issue

Tags: android, ios, cakephp, video, ffmpeg

I am on `cakephp 2.3` and with my API, the video recorded from iPhone is not playing well in some android devices. So after wasting 2 week and with the help of community the solution was to convert this `mov` into `mp4` on server, **ffmpeg** lib was suggested.

I had installed `ffmpeg` lib, I am looking for any **cakephp 2.3.* version** package which works/converts with `ffmpeg`?

The other way I have is to use `php exec` and convert the video without php library.

Any suggestion/feedback welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the EXEC approach in the past and it worked fine, using a dedicated backend server process.

However, there is a well supported FFMPEG PHP library available which might better suit your needs:

- https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Either way, and something you are probably aware of but I'll say it anyway, one thing to watch is that video manipulation is very compute intensive so it is generally not something you would want to do on the server that is hosting your front end web service, for example.

Comment: Yes, video manipulation is very compute intensive, but my client requirements are as such that I don't have any other option. Thanks for your reply. I am using php exec function only.